# sklearn Convert Text Series to Sparse Matrix, Then Scale Numeric, Then Combine Into Single X

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

If I have both text and numeric values, and I want to:

1. Convert the text to numeric (I'm using `CountVectorizer` as a general example)
2. Convert numeric data to the same scale
3. Combine 1 and 2 into a single `X` matrix to pass to an estimator

How do I combine a sparse matrix and numpy array into a single `X` while being mindful about memory limitations when dealing with huge sparse matrices?

Here is an example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Term': [ 'johns company', 'johns company home', 'home repair',
            'home remodeling', 'johns company home repair system',
            'home repair systems', 'home systems', 'repair a home',
            'home remodeling ideas', 'home repair system'],
    'Metric1': [ 319434, 21644, 113185, 73210, 8907, 23016, 36789, 48025, 29624,
               6944],
    'Metric2': [13270, 5015, 4301, 3722, 2502, 2190, 1934, 2468, 2706, 904],
    'Metric3': [ 24170.83, 11034.36, 24137.57, 16548.53, 4777.27, 9565.45,
               8014.29, 9041.97, 7612.31, 4045.37],
    'Metric4': [1.0, 1.1, 2.9, 2.7, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 1.9, 1.6, 1.5],
    'y': [712, 406, 297, 215, 190, 0, 125, 100, 94, 93]
    }, columns=['Term', 'Metric1', 'Metric2', 'Metric3', 'Metric4', 'y'])

## df looks like this
                               Term  Metric1  Metric2   Metric3  Metric4    y
0                     johns company   319434    13270  24170.83      1.0  712
1                johns company home    21644     5015  11034.36      1.1  406
2                       home repair   113185     4301  24137.57      2.9  297
3                   home remodeling    73210     3722  16548.53      2.7  215
4  johns company home repair system     8907     2502   4777.27      1.1  190
5               home repair systems    23016     2190   9565.45      2.0    0
6                      home systems    36789     1934   8014.29      3.0  125
7                     repair a home    48025     2468   9041.97      1.9  100
8             home remodeling ideas    29624     2706   7612.31      1.6   94
9                home repair system     6944      904   4045.37      1.5   93
```

My intent here is to convert text to numbers.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
text_features = cv.fit_transform(df['Term'])
text_features
<10x8 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 27 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

My intent here is to normalize numeric X values.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
ss = StandardScaler()
num_features = ss.fit_transform(df[['Metric1', 'Metric2', 'Metric3', 'Metric4']])
num_features
array([[ 2.81861161,  2.81931317,  1.76781103, -1.22081006],
       [-0.52069075,  0.3351711 , -0.12390699, -1.08208165],
       [ 0.50581477,  0.12031011,  1.76302143,  1.41502985],
       [ 0.05755051, -0.05392589,  0.67016134,  1.13757301],
       [-0.66351856, -0.42105531, -1.02495954, -1.08208165],
       [-0.50530567, -0.51494414, -0.33543744,  0.1664741 ],
       [-0.35086055, -0.59198114, -0.55881232,  1.55375826],
       [-0.22486438, -0.43128678, -0.41082121,  0.02774568],
       [-0.4312061 , -0.35966646, -0.61669947, -0.38843957],
       [-0.68553089, -0.90193466, -1.13035684, -0.52716798]])
```

My intent here is join `text_features` and `num_features` in efforts to make one single `X` to pass to an estimator.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
fu = FeatureUnion([('text', text_features), ('num', num_features)])
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(fu, df['y'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#230>", line 1, in <module>
    lr.fit(fu, df['y'])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 427, in fit
    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 510, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 393, in check_array
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'FeatureUnion'
```

Is `FeatureUnion` what I should be trying to use here to join text and numeric data into a single `X` matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `FeatureUnion` works. `FeatureUnion` applies multiple feature extractors / preprocessors and combines the resulting features into a single matrix. Since you do not have multiple preprocessors, but instead have multiple matricies, you should probably use `hstack` instead. Using `numpy.hstack()` it requires two dense matrices. If sparse is desired instead, use `scipy.sparse.hstack()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion. I now see that `np.hstack((text_features.todense(), num_features))` does create a single `X`.  That returns a matrix.  Alternatively, `np.hstack((text_features.toarray(), num_features))` returns an ndarray.